# Enum inside a JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Is there a way to use Enum values inside a JSP without using scriptlets.

e.g.

```
package com.example;

public enum Direction {
    ASC,
    DESC
}
```

so in the JSP I want to do something like this

```
<c:if test="${foo.direction ==<% com.example.Direction.ASC %>}">...
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could implement the web-friendly text for a direction within the enum as a field:

```
<%@ page import="com.example.Direction" %>
...
<p>Direction is <%=foo.direction.getFriendlyName()%></p>
<% if (foo.direction == Direction.ASC) { %>
<p>That means you're going to heaven!</p>
<% } %>
```

but that mixes the view and the model, although for simple uses it can be view-independent ("Ascending", "Descending", etc).

Unless you don't like putting straight Java into your JSP pages, even when used for basic things like comparisons.

Answer (score 5):

It can be done like this I guess

```
<c:set var="ASC" value="<%=Direction.ASC%>"/>
<c:if test="${foo.direction == ASC}"></c:if>
```

the advantage is when we refactor it will reflect here too

Comment: Why did you unvote it? Please comment the reason.

Comment: If its because JSP expression look at the accepted answer he is also using it

Answer (score 2):

You can simply check against the enum value as a string:

```
<c:if test="${foo.direction == 'ASC'}">...
```

Comment: Using hard-coded String is a bad idea

Comment: Avoid hardcoded Strings. What if your enum is changed ?

Comment: Perhaps this is not the best solution. But it is still better than bulky Java code in JSP page.