# JSP: accessing enum inside JSP EL tags

Tags: jsp

My java enum looks like this:

```
public enum EmailType { HOME, WORK, MOBILE, CUSTOMER_SERVICE, OTHER }
```

In JSP, I am trying to do sth like below, which is not working.

```
<c:choose>
          <c:when test="${email.type == EmailType.HOME}">(Home)</c:when>
          <c:when test="${email.type == EmailType.WORK}">(Work)</c:when>
</c:choose>
```

After googling, I found these links: [Enum inside a JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163407/enum-inside-a-jsp). But, I want to avoid using scriplets in my JSP. How can I access the java enum inside EL tag and do the comparision?? Please help.

Comment: Duplicate of [In JSP EL enum value always empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606673/in-jsp-el-enum-value-always-empty). Just treat them as strings.

Comment: Feel like it is not duplicate for the following reasons: enum EmailType is written in a separate java file(EmailType.java), which contains no methods.

Comment: My email entity looks like this: public class Email { ... EmailType type; ....}

Comment: EmailType.java contains: public enum EmailType { HOME, WORK, MOBILE, CUSTOMER_SERVICE, OTHER }

Comment: Did you for instance **read** the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606673/in-jsp-el-enum-value-always-empty/4606717#4606717) on the linked dupe?

Comment: Thxs. Let me give it a try and confirm if it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When an enum is serialized it becomes a string.  So just use a string compare.

```
<c:choose>
          <c:when test="${email.type == 'HOME'}">(Home)</c:when>
          <c:when test="${email.type == 'WORK'}">(Work)</c:when>
</c:choose>
```